Regular spherical quadrilateral tiling for a game board
Are there constructions for tiling a sphere with mostly regular spherical quadrilaterals, but with correction spherical polygons whose number and total area are minimized?
In other words, a corrected regular spherical quadrilateral tiling better than that achieved by the soccer-ball tiling, where "better" is defined as having fewer correction spherical polygons and with a smaller total area of correction?
My actual interest is in the playing of the game of go on a sphere, where pieces are placed on the vertices of the regular spherical quadrilaterals, and the correction vertices are grayed or whited out of view.

"soccer-ball" is one of the many  Johnson's solids... You should find in this reference volumes better taylored to your needs...

You could play it on a cube, watching out for the eight corners.   The points would be $(x,y,N)$ and so on.  The squash them down to a sphere, the points are $(x/r,y/r,N/r)$ where $r^2=x^2+y^2+N^2$.

My intuition says that most of a sphere can be tiled with regular spherical quadrilaterals, with the exception of six areas, that would contain the same spherical polygon. The six areas would be the north and south poles, and four equally-spaced areas around the equator. But are all these areas equally-spaced around the sphere in solid/spherical degrees? I don't know. Is my intuition correct? I don't know.

"squash them down to a sphere" This wouldn't yield a spherical playing field, one that could be rotated during play, or be projected from multiple directions onto a plane to show the playing board from different directions.

The best tool for this job is the Euler characteristic. It tells us that after tiling the sphere with polygons, the total number of polygons, minus the number of edges, plus the number of vertices, is always $2$.
If you want only quadrilaterals, and you want most vertices to be a meeting between 4 quadrilaterals, but some places 3 quadrilaterals meet, you can use the Euler characteristic to deduce that there must be 8 of these degenerate vertices.
If, instead, you really want 4 polygons to each vertex, then you need to use some other polygons. Triangles would probably be the most ergonomic choice. Again, the Euler characteristic will let us deduce that there are 8 of them. Their size does not matter. There will be eight triangles, and the number of triangles will be eight.

How does the Euler characteristic tell us these things? Let's tackle the first case first. Say you have $N$ quadrilaterals. Each quadrilateral has $4$ edges, but each edge is shared by $2$ quadrilaterals, so the total number of edges in the tiling is $2N$ (intuitively, each quadrilateral contributes 4 "half-edges" to the tiling).
Finally, let's say we have $V$ 4-vertices and $W$ 3-vertices. There are $N$ quadrilaterals, so the total degree of all vertices is $4N$. But the total degree of all vertices is also $4V + 3W$. These must be equal.
This gives us two equations: $4N = 4V + 3W$, and the Euler characteristic $N - 2N + (V + W) = 2$. This might seem like 2 eqautions in 3 unknowns, but we can actually isolate $W$ here and see that it is equal to $8$.

As for the triangle case, we can solve it this way: Say we have $Q$ quadrilaterals and $T$ triangles. Then the number of polygons is $Q + T$. The number of edges is $\frac{4Q + 3T}{2}$. And the number of vertices is $\frac{4Q + 3T}{4}$. Inserting into the Euler characteristic, we get
$$
Q + T - \frac{4Q + 3T}{2} + \frac{4Q + 3T}{4} = 2
$$
After a little algebra, we can conclude that $T = 8$.

Why is the Euler characteristic true? Take any tiling you want, and build it up. Start with a single edge, two vertices, and a somewhat degenereate  2-gon (yes, we can allow a polygon to "own" both sides of an edge here). The Euler characteristic holds.
Now add the edges of your tiling one by one, always staying connected to the edges we already have. Each new edge will either yield a new vertex, or split a polygon in two, but never both. So every single edge you add, the Euler characteristic still holds. So it must still hold after you add the final edge to your tiling.

Is there a picture of such a construction, with 8 degenerate locations, available on the Web? I realize that asking for a 2-dimensional picture of a three-dimensional tiling doesn't make complete sense.

@DavidSpector The simplest ones in either case are the cube and the octahedron. But that's probably too small and too pathological for you. The next step up might be this one and this one. Note that the two different cases (triangles versus degree-3 vertices) are duals of eachother. Which is to say, essentially, if you have a polyhedron of one type and play go on the vertices, then playing go on the faces instead (heresy, I know) will essentially yield the other type.

Thank you, Arthur, but neither the rhombicuboctahedron nor the deltoidal icositetrahedron meet the needs stated in this question.

@DavidSpector I suspected as much. You want a larger example. A regular go board has over 350 vertices, while these examples have 26 and 24. They are way too small. I don't think I can give you that. But I can still tell you that the number of "corrections" you need will be 8, regardless of the size you make your sphere.

You could use an $n\times n\times n$ cube, projected out to a sphere. Note that the squares will not become identical spherical quadrilaterals, but that is unavoidable (because the angles joining at a vertex must add up to 360 but the angles of a spherical quadrilateral add up to more than 360).
